# Nested NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to simulate a Stackelberg Competition model in Mathematica, where the problem is:

Player 1 has utility function `f[x, y, z]` and plays first. He can choose any x and y to maximize his utility.

Player 2 has utility function `g[x, y, z]`. He uses the values of x and y chosen by player 1 as constants and maximizes his utility function with respect to z.

But since player 1 moves first, he can anticipate what player 2 will choose for z given his x and y, so he can use that anticipated value in his maximization problem.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to do something like this with nested NMaximums?

```
NMaximize[{f[x, y, z], z == NMaximize[{g[x, y, z]},{z}]}, {x, y, z}]
```

In other words, maximize a function f with respect to x, y, z with the constraint that z must also be the global maximum of another function g, which takes in x, y, z as parameters but is maximized only with respect to z (i.e. holds x and y constant).

Comment: Please include the code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Find the $z$-value that maximizes $g$ for given $(x,y)$:

```
gmaxz[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := z /. Last[NMaximize[g[x, y, z], z]]
```

Maximize $f$ with this constraint:

```
NMaximize[f[x, y, gmaxz[x, y]], {x, y}]
```

### Example

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] = -7.73047 + 12.4246 x - 5.32774 x^2 + 6.34827 y - 7.01951 x y - 4.20797 y^2 + 8.61072 z - 5.36802 x z + 0.709316 y z - 4.2479 z^2;
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] = -5.18563 - 5.24892 x - 1.52711 x^2 + 1.30878 y - 1.01261 x y - 3.66432 y^2 - 4.61903 z - 1.37142 x z + 4.29875 y z - 2.77395 z^2;

gmaxz[0.2, 0.3]
(*    -0.649559    *)

NMaximize[f[x, y, gmaxz[x, y]], {x, y}]
(*    {-4.35823, {x -> -1.12368, y -> 2.32255}}    *)
```